# OpenCV Video Output image not showing

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Why is the camera preview is not showing on the output screen/frame?

Here is the screenshot of the output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

x = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```